# filter object from array of object by given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an array of JSON like below

```js
const data = [
  {
    "uniqueId": 1233,
    "serviceTags": [
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "FRRRR",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      }
    ],
    
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": 34555,
    "serviceTags": [
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "JWJN2",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      }
    ],
    
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": 44422,
    "serviceTags": [
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "ABC",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "BBC",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      }
    ],
    
  }
]
```

I want to filter array of object by below tagId

```
const tagId = ['ABC','FRRRR'];
```

filter array of json  should be like

```
[
  {
    "uniqueId": 1233,
    "serviceTags": [
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "FRRRR",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      }
    ],
    
  },
 
  {
    "uniqueId": 44422,
    "serviceTags": [
      {
        "Id": 11602,
        "tagId": "ABC",
        "missingRequired": [
          
        ],
        "summaries": [
          {
            "contract": "ACTIVE",
            
          },
          {
            "contract": "INACTIVE",
            
          }
        ],
        "lttributes": {
          
        }
      }
      
    ],
    
  }
]
```

try to do by below way but I am not able to get exact output

```
const r = data.filter(d => d.serviceTags.every(c => tagId.includes(c.tagId)));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: If you use `some()` instead of `every()` in your attempt it will filter the required objects out, but won't filter the `serviceTags` arrays themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filtering as desired, you would have to map each element to elements that only include the desired `tagId`s as follows:

```js
const 
    data = [ { "uniqueId": 1233, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "FRRRR", "missingRequired": [ ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE", }, { "contract": "INACTIVE", } ], "lttributes": { } } ], }, { "uniqueId": 34555, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "JWJN2", "missingRequired": [ ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE", }, { "contract": "INACTIVE", } ], "lttributes": { } } ], }, { "uniqueId": 44422, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "ABC", "missingRequired": [ ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE", }, { "contract": "INACTIVE", } ], "lttributes": { } }, { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "BBC", "missingRequired": [ ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE", }, { "contract": "INACTIVE", } ], "lttributes": { } } ], } ],
    
    tagId = ['ABC','FRRRR'],
    
    r = data.map(
        ({serviceTags,...rest}) => ({rest,serviceTags:serviceTags.filter(
            ({tagId:tid}) => tagId.includes(tid)
        )})
    )
    .filter(d => d.serviceTags.every(c => tagId.includes(c.tagId)));


console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the result in the desired form.

For each item in the `data` array, we check if any service tags match, using Array.filter().

If we get any matches we add the item to the result.

```js
const data = [ { "uniqueId": 1233, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "FRRRR", "missingRequired": [  ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE",  }, { "contract": "INACTIVE",  } ], "lttributes": {  } } ],  }, { "uniqueId": 34555, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "JWJN2", "missingRequired": [  ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE",  }, { "contract": "INACTIVE",  } ], "lttributes": {  } } ],  }, { "uniqueId": 44422, "serviceTags": [ { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "ABC", "missingRequired": [  ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE",  }, { "contract": "INACTIVE",  } ], "lttributes": {  } }, { "Id": 11602, "tagId": "BBC", "missingRequired": [  ], "summaries": [ { "contract": "ACTIVE",  }, { "contract": "INACTIVE",  } ], "lttributes": {  } } ],  } ]

const tagId = ['ABC','FRRRR'];
const result = data.reduce((acc, { serviceTags, ...item}) => {
     const matchingTags = serviceTags.filter(st => tagId.includes(st.tagId));
     if (matchingTags.length) { 
         acc.push({ 
             ...item,
             serviceTags: matchingTags
         })
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to the `reduce()` option is to `map()` the data with a nested filter on the `serviceTags` and then `filter()` the result to remove those entries with empty arrays.

```js
const data = [{ uniqueId: 1233, serviceTags: [{ Id: 11602, tagId: 'FRRRR', missingRequired: [], summaries: [{ contract: 'ACTIVE', }, { contract: 'INACTIVE', },], lttributes: {}, },], }, { uniqueId: 34555, serviceTags: [{ Id: 11602, tagId: 'JWJN2', missingRequired: [], summaries: [{ contract: 'ACTIVE', }, { contract: 'INACTIVE', },], lttributes: {}, },], }, { uniqueId: 44422, serviceTags: [{ Id: 11602, tagId: 'ABC', missingRequired: [], summaries: [{ contract: 'ACTIVE', }, { contract: 'INACTIVE', },], lttributes: {}, }, { Id: 11602, tagId: 'BBC', missingRequired: [], summaries: [{ contract: 'ACTIVE', }, { contract: 'INACTIVE', },], lttributes: {}, },], },];

const tagId = ['ABC', 'FRRRR'];

const r = data
  .map((d) => ({
    ...d,
    serviceTags: d.serviceTags.filter((c) => tagId.includes(c.tagId)),
  }))
  .filter((d) => d.serviceTags.length);

console.log(r);
```